# Python-Redmine Unable to concat custom_field value to issues

Tags: python, pandas, redmine, python-redmine

I am unable to get the custom fields value merged on the issues. The results look like this.[image]

I am looking to have those lines merged together so that it would look more like 
669 | 253652 | 10 
671 | 118387 | 10

Here is my code that I am attempting to do this with.

```py
results=[]
issues = redmine.issue.filter(project_id=your_project)
df =pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id','subject', 'project', 'tracker', 'status', 'priority', 'author', 'category', 'due_date', 'so','description', 'need qty'])
for issue in issues:
    results.append(issue)
for issue in results:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'id' : issue.id,'subject' : issue.subject , 'project' : issue.project, 'tracker' : issue.tracker, 'status' : issue.status, 'priority' : issue.priority,
        'author' : issue.author, 'category' : issue.category, 'due_date' : issue.due_date, 'description' : issue.description}])], ignore_index = True)
    for custom in issue.custom_fields:
        if (custom.name == 'Need Qty'):
            df=pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'need qty' : custom.value}])], ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : [669, 670, 671, 672],
    'Column2' : [12345, None, 67890, None],
    'Column3' : [None, 10, None, 10]
})
df['Column3'] = df['Column3'].shift(-1)
df = df.dropna()
df
```

Comment: So this does fix my issue. But is this more of correcting a problem after it happens? Like shouldn't I be able to have the custom_field merge right on to the same row as the issues?

Comment: You probably can, however, without being able to see the initial data and a couple other things it would be really hard to set the code to be able to account for problems like that. This the best that I can do without having more information unfortunately.